# Problem with advanced "kick" command, discord.py v2

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My "kick" command has a problem with the condition that it will return an error. Perhaps the problem isn't in the code, but in the role settings in Discord.
In short, with this command, the user can kick himself, as well as a member with the same role (for example, Moderator). I would like it to throw an error when trying to kick myself or a person with the same role. Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Optional
from .. import Plugin
from core import Bot
from discord import app_commands, Interaction, Member


def can_moderate():
    async def predicate(interaction: Interaction):
        target: Member = interaction.namespace.member or interaction.namespace.target
        if not target: return True
        assert interaction.guild is not None and isinstance(interaction.user, Member)

        if (
            target.top_role.position > interaction.user.top_role.position
            or target.guild_permissions.kick_members
            or target.guild_permissions.ban_members
            or target.guild_permissions.administrator
            or target.guild_permissions.manage_guild
        ):
            raise app_commands.CheckFailure(f"You can't kick **{target}**")
        return True
    
    return app_commands.check(predicate)


class Moderation(Plugin):
    def __init__(self, bot: Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command(name = "kick", description = "Kick a member")
    @app_commands.default_permissions(kick_members = True)
    @app_commands.describe(member = "Select a member", reason = "Specify a reason for the kick")
    async def kick_command(self, interaction: Interaction, member: Member, reason: Optional[str]):
        if not reason: reason = "not specified"
        try:
            await member.kick(reason = reason)
        except:
            await self.bot.error(f"I'm sorry, but I can't kick **{member}**", interaction)
        else:
            await self.bot.success(f"**{member}** has been kicked  from the server.", interaction)


async def setup(bot: Bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Moderation(bot))
```

Thank you in advance for your help❤️!

Tried to change the conditions, something like that:

```
        if (
            target.top_role.position >= interaction.user.top_role.position
            or target.guild_permissions.kick_members
            or target.guild_permissions.ban_members
            or target.guild_permissions.administrator
            or target.guild_permissions.manage_guild
            or target.id == interaction.user.id
        ):
            raise app_commands.CheckFailure(f"You can't kick **{target}**")
        return True
```

Comment: Why not check something like `if member.id == interaction.author.id` within the command instead of making it a function?

Comment: Your condition check is not correct... You should say `... or not target.guild_permissions.kick_members ...` same as other permissions you checked

Comment: Still can kick myself and members with same role

Comment: Where are you calling can_moderate()?

Comment: I already fix it, lost `@can_moderate()` after `@app_commands.default_permissions(kick_members = True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making it a function and overcomplicating things, you can simply do some checks before kicking a member.

Since you are making this a `kick` function only, we can simply add it to the command as it won't make a difference.

**New code:**

```py
async def kick(self, interaction: Interaction, member: Member, reason: str = None):

if member.top_role <= interaction.author.top_role or member.id == interaction.author.id or member.id == interaction.me.id: # Add more checks here
    return # Your message here
```

Add more conditions if you need but keep in mind the format.